# FLEX - Tween videoPlayer.seek()

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, tween, gsap

I need to play forwards/backwards to target frame(or second) on my videoPlayer when I push a button. How would I do this?

Not sure how to tween the seek() property. I have TweenLite, which normally works great! But just not sure how to do it here.. :)

Thanks!

Comment: You can only seek to keyframes and if you add a key frame on every frame then you are basically just storing a collection of still images, and you aren't getting any benefits of it being a "video". You may want to rethink your approach

Comment: That is true. What would be the best way to be able to scroll through frames 1-by-1 forwards/backwards?
I'm rendering an animation frame by frame, and want to be able to move forwards/backwards smoothly through the frames.

Comment: Even if there are no benefits of it being a "video", dealing with video object instead of bunch of images seems to be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disregarding the approach, you can animate a simple `Object` with `TweenLite` and update `seek` property accordingly:

```
var obj:Object = {prop:0};
TweenLite.to(obj, duration, {prop:desiredFrame, onUpdate:updateSeek});
function updateSeek():void
{
  videoPlayer.seek(obj.prop);
}
```